# Cauchy-Schwarz Like Inequality

Tags: analysis

I want to prove the following for $p > 1$.
$$\left | \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right|^p \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p$$
My first idea was to use Cauchy-Schwarz with $\mathbf{X} = (x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ and $\mathbf{Y} = \frac{1}{n}\mathbf{1}$. We would get:
$$|\langle \mathbf{X}, \mathbf{Y} \rangle| = \left | \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\right| \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2\right)^{1/2}$$
However I still find a few problems, since I can't simply raise both sides to the $p$. So any ideas? I thought about using Holder or Minkowski, but I struggled a little bit.

Comment: hint: holders inequality on the series $\sum_{j=1}^n (1*|x_j|)$ i.e. $(\sum_{j=1}^n  |x_j|^p)^{1/p}(\sum_{j=1}^n 1)^{1/q}$ use the triangle inequality too

Comment: This is just convexity of the function $x \to x^{p}$.